# Fortify audit workbench

Tags: fortify

While converting the audited .fpr files to pdf in audit workbench for fortify scan results, only one issue's comment under each category is present in the pdf file. On what basis is the tool selecting which issue's comment to print in the pdf?
Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to generate legacy report, Pop up will show up.

On the top you will find button for "Visibility Setting" , this will show another pop up for showing Suppressed/ Removed / Hidden issues. [HP fortify snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpRoM.jpg).

Also "Issue Breakdown by Analysis" tab also gives control while adding issues